# Not able to browse Kubernetes dashboard for clusters created in Azure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-dashboard

Trying to access Kubernetes dashboard (Azure AKS) by using below command but getting error as attached.

```
az aks browse --resource-group rg-name --name aks-cluster-name --listen-port 8851
```

[image: Kubernetes dashboard browing error]

Comment: are you able run any kubectl command ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I tried this and got output - "kubectl config view"

Comment: try `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I am getting output for it too.

Comment: is this a azure ad enabled cluster ? can you try with token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read AKS documentation of how to authenticate the dashboard from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-dashboard). This also explains about how to enable the addon for newer version of k8s also.

Pasting here for reference

**Use a kubeconfig**

For both Azure AD enabled and non-Azure AD enabled clusters, a kubeconfig can be passed in. Ensure access tokens are valid, if your tokens are expired you can refresh tokens via kubectl.

1. Set the admin kubeconfig with `az aks get-credentials -a --resource-group <RG_NAME> --name <CLUSTER_NAME>`
2. Select `Kubeconfig` and click `Choose kubeconfig file` to open file selector
3. Select your kubeconfig file (defaults to $HOME/.kube/config)
4. Click Sign In

**Use a token**

1. For non-Azure AD enabled cluster, run `kubectl config view` and copy the token associated with the user account of your cluster.
2. Paste into the token option at sign in.
3. Click Sign In

For Azure AD enabled clusters, retrieve your AAD token with the following command. Validate you've replaced the resource group and cluster name in the command.

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.users[?(@.name == "clusterUser_<RESOURCE GROUP>_<AKS_NAME>")].user.auth-provider.config.access-token}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this

`kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')`.

You will get many values for some other keys such as Name, Labels, ..., token . The important one is the token that related to your name. Then copy that token and paste it.

Comment: I ran the command and upon entering the token in UI, I am getting error message- "Unauthorized (401): Invalid credentials provided"